# Analysis of Nim-Like Game?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, nim

There are a finite number of heaps, each with a finite number of counters. Two players take turns; on each move, they may remove exactly one counter from any heap, and also, if the heap is of size $n$, add as many heaps of size $\leq n-1$ as they want to the board.

For example, if the board was $[1,2,3]$, the board could become $[2,3]$, $[1,1,1,1,1,1,3]$, or $[1,2]$ after a move.

Has anyone seen this game before? I skimmed [ONAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Numbers_and_Games) and Winning Ways but didn't see it. I'll also accept a description of the winning strategy.

Comment: I don't think the analysis is research-level, but it might be ok as a reference request.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from $[1,2,3]$ to $[1,2]$ in one move.

Comment: By the way, this is equivalent to Nim with one pile, though it takes a little effort to see the correspondence. The winning positions for the second player have an even number of heaps of each size. It's easy to find the nimber of a position base $2$.

Comment: @bof: That looks like a mistake, but you can move from $[1,2,3]$ to $[1,2,2,2]$ which is equivalent to $[1,2]$.

Comment: Again, the analysis of this game is an exercise. The only way this might be on-topic is as a reference request. Perhaps people have looked at families of games on partitions generalizing this one.

Comment: @DouglasZare I thought **every** Nim-type game was equivalent to Nim with only one pile?

Comment: bof: I wouldn't say that. First, some Nim-type games are equivalent to Nim with one pile of size up to $n$. Second, there are infinitely many moves possible when you have a heap of size greater than $1$, so a priori there could be infinite ordinal nimbers necessary to describe the game.